# Can't move QDockWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qmainwindow, qdockwidget

I want to create a widget that contains several `QDockWidgets` on purpose of putting it into a `QMainWindow`. Problem is that if I add `QDockWidgets` to my `QWidget` class with `layout->addWidget(dockWidget);`(I don't know any other way of doing it) and then `setLayout(layout)` I can't do anything to the `QDockWidgets` but dock and undock. I can't move them, I can't position them in another place.

`QMainWindow` has this feature `addWidgets` that `QWidget` doesn't have. Using `QMainWindow` everything works perfect, but I want it to work the same if I add a `QWidget` object(containing some `QDockWidgets`) to `QMainWindow`.

Is there any possibility to make my `QWidget` fully support those `QDockWidgets`, and use the on full potential(move, scale, dock, change position)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a lot of `QDockWidgets`, simply enabling [dock nesting](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#dockNestingEnabled-prop) might be the solution to the underlying problem.

If you absolutely need to have a widget inside the `QMainWindow`, you can try putting another `QMainWindow` in the first one. You might have to set the [windowFlags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) property of the second `QMainWindow` to `Qt::Widget`.

Comment: +1 Agreed, having dock widgets behave as you expect _requires_ a `QMainWindow`, but can it make essentially invisible.  The same technique works for adding toolbar regions inside container widgets.